# beet stock shelf life

Tags: beets

How long will beet stock be good in the fridge and is it obvious (odor or otherwise) if it's bad.  I've had this beet stock for a while and I want to drink it but I'm a little nervous.
It smells fine and looks fine.

Comment: How long exactly have you had it, and how was it made?  Can you provide a picture?

Comment: For everything cooked (unless following a special recipe intended for preservation), the fridge shelf life is 3-5 days. See the attached quesiton; we don't want to repeat this for every single food item one can cook.

Answer (score 1):

Beet stock (the cooking liquor left over after boiling beetroot) contains plenty of nutrients, and hence it's a good breeding ground for mould and bacteria.

I would treat it like cooked vegetables, and throw it on the compost heap (or down the drain) if not consumed after a week in the fridge.

Of course it could be preserved for longer if steps were taken to combat mould/bacteria:

- reduced to a syrup, perhaps with added sugar
- with lots of added salt, as in a pickling brine
- sterilised in an airtight container